# Application crash when using sendAsynchronously with RKRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I want to use Restkit to download a file asynchronously. However the application crash when sendAsynchronously method was used. If I used sendSynchronously instead of sendAsynchronously, it didn't crash. Is there anybody know why?

Here is my code

```
NSString *passURL = @"https://s3.amazonaws.com/mheydt-mhtnd/2012-03-13-1.png";
        RKRequest *request = [RKRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: passURL]];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request sendAsynchronously];


- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(RKResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response {
   NSLog(@"didLoadResponse");   
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the stack trace from the crash?

Comment: There was nothing log in the log. Here is the stack trace  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14181582/_temp/bugs/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-10%20at%201.42.23%20PM.png

Comment: Odd, it's crashing in `RKResponse` `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods because `_delegate` seems to have gone away.  In this case, `_delegate` is `self`  Is `self` getting deallocated before the delegate call-backs?

Answer (score 0):

When using `sendAsynchronously` in this way, the request is not retained. You would better use the `send` method which adds the request in an instance of `RKRequestQueue` (which prevents the request to be freed too soon):

```
[request send];
```

**Or**, you can strongly reference the request by yourself. Your code would become:

```
@interface MyClass
{
    RKRequest *request;
}
```

We assume that this is a strong reference. And in the implementation, you would have:

```
@implementation MyClass

- (void)sendTheRequest
{
    NSString *passURL = @"https://s3.amazonaws.com/mheydt-mhtnd/2012-03-13-1.png";
    request = [RKRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: passURL]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request sendAsynchronously];
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(RKResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    request = nil;
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"didLoadResponse");
    request = nil;
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailLoadWithError");
    request = nil;
}

@end
```